In Azure dashboard - give user access to a single App Server, SQL Database, & Azure Storage
I want to have my QA team do some load testing of the dev slot of our web app. I want to give them full administrative access to the dev slot app service and its associated SQL Database and BLOB Storage. I do not want them to have any administrative access to anything else. (I trust them, but people sometimes click the wrong button.)
Is there a way to do this? And if so, how.
Also, if the answer is to put it in a distinct subscription, can I swap the app service instance between subscriptions.

You can use Azure role-based access control (Azure RBAC) to grant them the necessary permissions. You can create a custom role that includes the necessary permissions and assign it to the QA team at the subscription level. This will give them access to the specific resources they need without giving them access to anything else.

For swapping the app service instance between subscriptions, it is possible to do so using Azure PowerShell or Azure CLI. You can move the app service instance to a different resource group or subscription by using the Move-AzResource cmdlet in PowerShell or the az resource move command in CLI.

@NaveenSharma If you write this up as an answer, listing out the specifics to do this, happy to accept it. thanks


I want my QA team to do some load testing on the dev slot of our web app. I want to give them full administrative access to the dev slot app service and its associated SQL Database and BLOB Storage. I do not want them to have any administrative access to anything else. (I trust them, but people sometimes click the wrong button.)

To control user access to specific resources, first create a group and add the people you need to give access to, then create custom roles.

Note: that you need either Owner or User Access Administrator roles to create a custom RBAC role.

Access to custom roles can only be restricted at the following levels: management group, subscription, and resource group.
In your scenario, keep App Services, SQL database, and Blob storage in a single resource group and create the custom role at the resource group level.
Portal:
Step 1:

Step 2:

In the Permissions tab, select all the necessary permissions according to your requirements as shown below.

In the Assignable scopes tab, ensure that the type is set to Resource group, then select Review + create.

Once you have created it, the validation will be performed, and the custom role will be created successfully.

Note: that this custom role will only be visible and accessible to the resources present in your resource group.

Now you can assign this role to your group of users to access the web app, Storage, and SQL database. This will restrict the user from accessing other resources.

If the answer is to put it in a distinct subscription, can I swap the app service instance between subscriptions?

Regarding swapping the App Service instance between subscriptions, you could refer to this MS-Document to use the PowerShell script.
Reference:
Move resources to a new subscription or resource group - Azure Resource Manager | Microsoft Learn
